# How to use Telegraf (Telegram) in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegraf, telegram-webhook

I'm trying use Telegraf library with Firebase Functions but it's not working as I expected.

I follow these [this article](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-f76b5506179) and instructions as appear in [webhooks (as appears for express example)](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=webhooks) and [webhookcallback](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=webhookcallback) as appear in telegraf docs.

```js
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime or Firestore Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

// set telegraf and responses.
const BOT_TOKEN = 'my-telegram-bot-token'
const bot = new Telegraf(BOT_TOKEN)
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply("Start instructions"))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply("This is help"))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hola'))
bot.on('text', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Response to any text'))
bot.catch((err, ctx) => {
  console.log(`Ooops, ecountered an error for ${ctx.updateType}`, err)
})

// initialize bot

bot.launch() // <-- (2)

//appends middleware 
exports.ideas2coolBot = functions.https.onRequest(bot.webhookCallback(`/my-path`));
```

In firebase server I need add **bot.launch()** (2) to get worked, but it works just for max timeout set in Firebase Function. I need to recall Telegram "[setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)" API to get work again and it works for the same time. It's like it's generate one function instance and shut down when time is over.

I noted the **[telegraf.launch()](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=launch)** have options to start in **poll** or **webhook** mode but its not pretty clear for me how to use this options.

How should I use **telegram.launch()** to get worked in webhook mode in Firebase?

**Edit:**
When I used [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) I get this result:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "url": "https://0dbee201.ngrok.io/test-app-project/us-central1/testAppFunction/bot",
        "has_custom_certificate": false,
        "pending_update_count": 7,
        "last_error_date": 1573053003,
        "last_error_message": "Read timeout expired",
        "max_connections": 40
    }
}
```

and console shows incoming conection but do nothing...

```sh
i  functions: Beginning execution of "ideas2coolBot"
i  functions: Finished "ideas2coolBot" in ~1s
```

**Edit2:**

I've been trying adding Express too...

```sh
app.use(bot.webhookCallback('/bot'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World from Firebase!')
})

exports.ideas2coolBot = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

it's works **'/'** path but got nothing with **'/bot'**. POST to **'/bot'** not response.

By the way, I tried a express standalone version and works prefect, but using it with firebase doesn't respond (**"Read timeout expired"**).

Comment: What does this have to do with the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: Nothing, thank for correction!

Comment: It's like "ctx.reply" function doesn't respond throw express or simply firebase discard "app.use" content.

Answer (score 8):

delete

```
bot.launch()
```

try add this

```
exports.YOURFUNCTIONNAME = functions.https.onRequest(
  (req, res) => bot.handleUpdate(req.body, res)
)
```

then set ur webhook manually

`https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOTTOKEN}/setWebhook?url={FIREBASE FUNCTION URL}'`

Comment: I added a link to this question in Telegraf's Issues: 
https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/555